# WPF Background Worker stops on Application exit

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have some tasks that need executing on application exit, before i used a Thread to execute these changes and displayed a Loading bar until it was done.

I am trying to convert the simple Thread to a Background Worker, and the problem is, that when i close the app, the Background Worker also quits, even though it still has tasks to perform.

Question, How do i prevent the Background Worker from quitting(just like a simple thread would do) on window close(application exit)?

The cancelation is set to false.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is just a class that makes running a background thread easier, not a Task Scheduler job or background service. You misunderstood what it does.

Comment: I have some modifications which are slow to do in runtime, execute at the closing of the application or on the save button pressed, what else can i use for this?

Comment: Why are you  trying to convert the thread into a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: For easyer progress monitoring, but anyway i found a way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around it, though it doesn't answer my initial question.

I will cancel the closing event, and from there start the background worker, when the background worker finishes i will close the app from the Worker Completed method.